# How can I know the laws of a specific country regarding drones?

Tags: regulations

<sub>Reworded from: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/112261/</sub>

If travelling to a few countries, I was wondering if there is one source for all the drone rules/laws of the countries I am travelling to instead of doing a specific search for each country.

Does such a source exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a large number of websites which collate drone rules in different countries; [to list a few](https://www.google.com/search?q=international+drone+laws):

- [Dronegenuity](https://www.dronegenuity.com/international-drone-laws-requirements/)
- [UAV Coach](https://uavcoach.com/drone-laws/)
- [Drone Rush](https://dronerush.com/international-drone-laws-16520/)
- [UAV Systems International](https://uavsystemsinternational.com/pages/drone-laws-by-country)

However, due to the rapidly evolving nature of drone rules these could quickly become out of date - in fact, at time of writing, some of the sites already contain old (now incorrect) information. The safest option is to check the website of the country's aviation regulator before you travel.

Comment: Some input about the quality of the information there: I checked the information about Austria. Austria changed the regulations in 2014, and there is a new change becoming effective in July 2020 (harmonization of EU wide regulations). Two of the websites have the old information which was correct before 2014! One has an invalid link to the responsible regulation body and one has the currently valid information but no hint that there are changes becoming effective in July 2020. So if you would use this information for your holiday in July or later, all would be wrong!

Answer (score 7):

<sub>Reworded from: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/112275/</sub>

This site will list all the drone rules/laws by country:

- https://uavsystemsinternational.com/pages/drone-laws-by-country

Note: It is still a good idea to check for yourself since the laws for that country could be out-of-date.

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer, isn't it? Is that allowed on DaMA.SE?

Comment: @Mast the question specifically asked for a source/link so I think it is fine, what do you think?